# eslint: New-line after case statement inside switch

Tags: switch-statement, coding-style, case, eslint

I want to add an eslint rule, which forces a new line after each case-statement inside a switch-case block.

Eslint shall validate my code-style as given in the following example:

invalid:

```
let foo;
switch (true) {
    case 1: foo = 'bar'; break;
    case 2: foo = 'blubb'; break;
    default: break;
}
```

valid:

```
let foo;
switch (true) {
    case 1:
        foo = 'bar';
        break;
    case 2:
        foo = 'blubb';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar (not quite the same) `eslint` rule proposal in [`eslint/eslint` issue 6619](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6619).

It is implemented (and can be tweaked) in [`lukeapage/eslint-plugin-switch-case`](https://github.com/lukeapage/eslint-plugin-switch-case): that can give you ideas on how to implement your own version of that rule.